# cipher text only attacks on deterministic homomorphic encryption schemes

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, ciphertext-only-attack

If we consider a set of numbers say a set $s=\{a,b,c,d\}$ , where $a,b,c,d>1$ and the numbers $a, b, c, d$ do not share any relation between them , i.e. for any two numbers,  $n_1,n_2\in s$ the following relations are guaranteed to hold: $n_1+n_2\neq 0$ and $n_1*n_2\neq 1$.

Is it possible to break the fully homomorphic encryption scheme on these set of numbers?

**Note**
This is a followup to [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24865/cipher-text-only-attacks-on-deterministic-fully-homomorphic-encryption-schemes) which does not restrict the set $s$ is at all.

Comment: Does the attacker know the public key?

Comment: I updated the question's formatting, etc. If I inadvertently changed the meaning of the question, please let me know.

Comment: public key is not a secret value. It is public to everyone.

Comment: If they have the public key, why not just use it to encrypt 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. If the input set does not have any identity element (for both mul and add operations) then one cannot construct a field and subsequently there cannot be homomorphic operations.  More clearly, if the input plaintext elements do not form a field (and their respective ciphertext elements do not form a field either)  then there cannot be homomorphisms of operations. This is by definition of [Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29).

So if the input set contains identity elements (and other properties needed to become a field) then while the given set members may not have any obvious relation. There would be some constant $c$ for which  $enc(n_1) + c * enc(n_2) = enc(0) $ subsequently finding which attacks mentioned in [previous question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24865/cipher-text-only-attacks-on-deterministic-fully-homomorphic-encryption-schemes) apply !

Also  an attacker could try to find random complex relations among them. For example is $ enc(a) + enc(a) = enc(b) $ or is $ enc(a) *enc( b) = enc(c) $ etc. revealing inferences.

Comment: yes the observation is correct. In all cases,for some constant c, it will satisfy the relation n1 + c * n2 = 0. so it is possible to break the scheme.

Comment: @sashank Do you have any reference or explanation about the impossibility of construct a homomorphic encryption scheme of a set that is not a field? I think it might be true, but, I don't know, it doesn't look a trivial assumption.

Comment: @VitorLima I dont have any reference but i added more explanation in the answer hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If your **fully** homomorphic scheme is asymmetric and  deterministic, then, it is already broken.

One could just encrypt the value one, $c_1 = E(pk, 1)$, then, adds $c_1$ to itself until

$c_1 + c_1 + ... + c_1 == E(pk, a)$

or

$c_1 + c_1 + ... + c_1 == E(pk, b)$

etc...

Comment: Yes this is valid too.