# Executing encrypted code?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I want a code 'black box' that receives data inputs, processes those inputs, then sends out the outputs.

I want the code to be encrypted, or somehow obfuscated.

Is there any known way to do achieve this outcome?

Comment: How should a processor know what to do if the code is encrypted?

Comment: http://www.boazbarak.org/Papers/obfuscate.pdf $\:$ http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/942 $\:$ http://security.stackexchange.com/q/24551/49075 $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I don't know.  I can imagine some kind of a key pair between the processor and the code.

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1710/how-to-construct-encrypted-functions-with-either-public-or-private-data

Comment: Indistinguishable obfuscation is the best achievable result.

Answer (score 1):

No, assuming your code is running in an environment completely controlled by an adversary (no TPM etc.). Note that if the instructions were encrypted in some way we assume an adversary could simply intercept them after they are decrypted.

Your best shot is to obfuscate the code making it cumbersome for someone else to grasp the logic behind it. This can never give you security in a cryptographic sense.